# sql greater than statement returns values less than and greater than

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know my issue is that the value is a string but how can I work around it and return the correct results?

Here is my query and an excerpt of the results returned

```
select [Count of Disk Errors], _ResourceGuid  from Inv_Hard_Disk_Errors
where _resourceguid in (select guid from vComputer where IsManaged = '1')
and [COUNT of Disk Errors] > '250'
order by 1 desc

Count of Disk Errors    _ResourceGuid
99                     DDDC8FDE-46CD-493F-8AB9-0570DECE9183
9                      005E111E-B04B-44C8-B6FE-37FBC9547B8D
88                     E6BB97E7-67AE-4DF5-BD44-C1612098B137
87                     A0EE300B-C449-4E3A-9B82-7442F3AEDF11
8                      9A73D013-D2BA-43DC-A213-EF8FC9789498
```

Comment: The results the way it's listed may be confusing.  The numbers being returned in the first column which is what is off are 99, 9, 88, 87, 8 which are all less than 250 and I'm only looking for values greater than 250

Comment: Store your count as integer instead of a char or varchar and this wouldn't be a problem. Your results suggest it's a character which will sort lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

```
select [Count of Disk Errors], _ResourceGuid  
from Inv_Hard_Disk_Errors
where _resourceguid in (select guid from vComputer where IsManaged = '1')
  and try_cast([COUNT of Disk Errors] as int) > 250
order by try_cast([COUNT of Disk Errors] as int) desc
```

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)